# To fetch slack channel details from channel name

Tags: api, slack

I am looking for API from slack to fetch slack channel details by channel name, but I couldn't find any. There are API's like from channel_id I can fetch channel details, but I am interested to fetch from channel name.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find this, I am looking for the same api to fetch channel name through id etc.